# Html-JS: Problem with show multiple divs with js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to use below code, using html,js & css to change select tag to radio buttons. when I use this for one div element, it works, but when is use multiple divs, the js code not work and by select another element, just the first selector opened and other not works. What's the problem in JS?

Here is the code:

```js
const selected = document.querySelector(".selected");
const optionsContainer = document.querySelector(".options-container");

const optionsList = document.querySelectorAll(".option");
const selectedList = document.querySelectorAll(".selected");

selectedList.forEach(o =>{
    o.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
        
        optionsContainer.classList.toggle("active");        
        
    });
});


optionsList.forEach(o =>{
    o.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
        selected.innerHTML = o.querySelector("label").innerHTML;
        optionsContainer.classList.remove("active");
    });
});
```

```css
.select-box {
    display: flex;
    width: 400px;
    flex-direction: column;
    
}

.select-box .options-container{
    background: #2f3640;
    color: #f5f6fa;
    max-height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    border-radius: 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
    order: 1;
}

.selected {
    background: #2f3640;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    color: #f5f6fa;
    position: relative;
    order: 0;
}

.selected::after{
    content: "";
    background: url("down-arrow.png");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 32px;
    right: 10px;
    top: 12px;
    
    transition: all 0.4s;
}


.select-box .options-container.active{

    max-height: 240px;
    opacity: 1;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    
}

.select-box .options-container.active + .selected::after{
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    top: -6px;
}

.select-box .options-container::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 8px;
    background: #0d141f;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}
.select-box .options-container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background: #525861;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}


.select-box .option,
.selected{
    padding: 12px 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.select-box .option:hover{
    background: #414b57;
}

.select-box label{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.select-box .option .radio{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="select-box">
    <div class="options-container">
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="student" name="job"   value="student">
        <label for="student">student</label>
      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="teacher" name="job" value="teacher">
        <label for="teacher">teacher</label>
      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="worker" name="job" value="worker">
        <label for="worker">Worker</label>
      </div>
                                                        
    </div>
    <div class="selected">
      Please Select
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br />

<div class="container">
  <div class="select-box">
    <div class="options-container">
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="work" name="favourite"   value="work">
        <label for="work">work</label>
      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="play" name="favourite" value="play">
        <label for="play">play</label>
      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="reading" name="favourite" value="reading">
        <label for="reading">reading</label>
      </div>
                                                        
    </div>
    <div class="selected">
      Please Select Your Favourite
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: Can I use 'for' loop for enable each div in js? Or what is the best way?

Comment: And I want to show this on all browsers correctly. What's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<label for="pet-select">Choose a pet:</label>
<select name="pets" id="pet-select">
    <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
    <option value="parrot">Parrot</option>
    <option value="spider">Spider</option>
    <option value="goldfish">Goldfish</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this is not the answer, I want to use just this code, I know about select tag, but I don't want to use that tag.

Comment: is there Any Solution?